# how to use jquery in codeigniter controller ? If I use this method I have to remove my other jquery code from my view?

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I have a jquery code in my view for search profile. search bar will appear on every page.I don't want to code this jquery in my every page ! so I want this jquery code in my controller my code in my view is here (This code working nicely in my view)

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#display1").hide();
$(".search").keyup(function(){

var searchbox1 = $(this).val();
var datastring = 'searchword='+ searchbox1;    
if(searchbox1=='')
 {

 }
 else 
{
$.ajax({
type:"post",                       

url: "http://localhost:1337/PhpProject1/search_profile_controller",
data:datastring,
success:function(html){                             
$("#display1").html(html).show();

},
error:function(e){                         
alert("error="+e);
}

})                

}    

})         
})
```

Comment: why dont you move the above script to a common javascript file and include it in all your views or if you are using any common layout file you can include the js file in that layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap this code in some `.js` file and upload it to your server folder to the path like: `/var/www/html/application/javascripts/search.js` save inside `search.js`:

I fixed some syntax and logic:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#display1").hide();
$(".search").keyup(function(){

    var searchbox1 = $(this).val();
    var datastring = 'searchword='+ searchbox1;

    if(searchbox1 != '')  {
        $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            url: "http://localhost:1337/PhpProject1/search_profile_controller",
            data:datastring,
            success:function(html){
                $("#display1").html(html).show();
            },
            error:function(e){
                alert("error="+e);
            }
        }); 
    }
    else
    {} //do nothing
  })
});
```

Then your view do this:

```
<?php
$obj =& get_instance();
$load_searchjs = '<script src="'.APPPATH.'/javascripts/search.js" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>';
$obj->router->fetch_class() === 'name_of_home_controller' ? $load_searchjs : ''; //if we are located in some controller (path) then load search.js 
?>
```